# Customize HTML output of DataList control of ASP.NET

Tags: c#, html, css, asp.net, datalist

How can I generate output of DataList control in the following format?

```
<ul id="container">
    <li data-genre="cricket"> Cricket Sport </li>
    <li data-genre="boxing"> Boxing Sport </li>
    <li data-genre="Swimming"> Swimming Sport </li>
    <li data-genre="Kite"> Kite Sport </li>
</ul>
```

Why I need to generates like this because of I need to apply following JQuery plugin
https://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/music.html

Following is DataList code. I am biding this List object on server side

```
<asp:DataList ID="dlSports" runat="server" RepeatColumns="6" CellSpacing="5" RepeatLayout="Table" >
<ItemTemplate>
       <image> Image will display here</image> 
       <span><%# Eval("SportName") %></span>
</ItemTemplate>                    
</asp:DataList>
```

I am using DataList because I need to display data in tabular form like showed in https://luis-almeida.github.io/filtrify/music.html.

------- EDITED -----------
HTML output like this.

```
<table id="MainContent_dlSports" cellspacing="5" class="text-center" style="height:100%;width:100%;">
 <tr>
        <td>
                    <li>
                        <image> ....</image> 
                     <span>Cricket Sport</span>
                    </li>
                </td>
        <td>
                    <li>
                        <image> ....</image> 
                     <span>Boxing Sport</span>
                    </li>
                </td>
               <td>
                    <li>
                        <image> ....</image> 
                     <span>Swimming Sport</span>
                    </li>
                </td>
</tr>
          .......
          .......
          .......
</table>
```

Comment: Can you provide current HTML output? Possibly some sort of jQuery tricks may apply to adjust generated HTML elements.

Comment: I don't really get the problem. You can place the UL inside the ItemTemplate and use Eval withing them `<li data-genre="<%# Eval("SportName") %>"><%# Eval("SportName") %></li>`

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto - I updated the questions. You can see HTML here. There is extra "tr, td" tags. I only need "li" tags because of applying jquery plugin as I mentioned in question

Comment: @VDWWD -  The problem is, there are tags in generated HTML output. You can see my updated question

Comment: You mean the `<li>` withing the `<td>`? They are probably generated by some jquery as they are not part of a normal DataList.

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="dlSports" runat="server" RepeatColumns="6" CellSpacing="5" RepeatLayout="Table" >
<ItemTemplate>
     <li>
       <image> Image will display here</image> 
       <span><%# Eval("SportName") %></span>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>                    
</asp:DataList>

Comment: @VDWWD.  I am using <li> in the itemtemplate.

Comment: That is not in present in the `ItemTemplate` in the question. But that still does not explain what it is you want. What tags are you talking about then?

Comment: @VDWWD - Because I need to apply JQuery plugin on data. For applying JQuery plugin, I need HTML in specfic format. Thats why I need customized HTML. I mentioned link of JQuery plugin in my question

Comment: If you want to get rid of the Table elements and create an UL, use a Repeater Control.

Comment: @VDWWD - Working fine with Repeater Control